# WCF Endpoint not working on IIS(Express)

Tags: wcf, iis, http-status-code-404, iis-express, endpoint

I'm trying to get an endpoint working on IIS (Express).
When debugging the project in VS with IIS Express and opening the endpoint address in my browser, I just get a normal 404 error.

My web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <services>
        <service name="A.B.C">
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:15000"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
          <endpoint address="Test" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="A.B.IC" bindingConfiguration="A.B.C">

          </endpoint>
        </service>
      </services>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="A.B.C"
                   maxBufferPoolSize="20971520"
                   maxBufferSize="2097152"
                   maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152">
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I place a .svc-Datei with the following contents into the website root, its working fine:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="A.B.C" CodeBehind="Services/C.svc.cs" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using IIS hosting you should not provide your own base address. The base address for the service is given by the location of a .svc file. The endpoint address is then relative to the .svc file

The .svc file is used by IIS to map the request to WCF (rather than, say, ASP.NET).

Now you can have a virtual .svc file rather than a physical one using [serviceActivations](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/fileless-activation-of-wcf-service-in-net-4-0/) or if you use ASpNetCompaibility to can remove the .svc part altogether using a ServiceRoute as [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2010/12/05/wcf-rest-on-.net-4.0.aspx) article shows

Comment: So adding
`<serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <serviceActivations>
          <add relativeAddress="Test123.svc" service="A.B.C"/>
        </serviceActivations>
      </serviceHostingEnvironment>`
, removing the `<host></host>`-section and changing the endpoint-adress to */Test* should open an endpoint at */Test123.svc/Test*?

Comment: Yes it should  (although you don;t need the / at the start of the address) and from looking at your config you should be able to get wsdl from /test123.svc?wsdl

Comment: Wow, it does. After having removed `<serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false"/>` from the `<behavior>`-section. Thanks! Is there a possibility to change the _maxBufferSize_ of _/Test123.svc_? I'm only adding the /Test123.svc/Test-Endpoint to be able to add a _bindingConfiguration_.

Comment: As long as you are on .NET 4 you can change the binding configuraiton without explicitly declaring an endpoint - just create an unnamed binding for basicHttpBinding with your settings. Any endpoint (including the default ones set up if you don't specify any will pick up these values without havingo to refer to them via a bindingConfiguration. If you're not on .NET 4 you have to do as you have

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question. When hosting over HTTP you need a .svc file so that the web server can instantiate the service. Other bindings such as net.tcp or net.msmq do not have this requirement.

Comment: This is not true for WAS hosting - WAS hosting by default requires a .svc file for any binding self hosting does not